# How to sanitize an email message with php and retain characters like the apostrophe?

Tags: php, email, security, phpmailer, sanitization

I'm sending mails from a form (user input).

I always did this:

```
filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Perfect. Except I found out that it will convert certain characters in HTML entities. The one you can see more often is apostrophe (`&#39`).

Obviously, no one wants to read `&#39` on a email message.

I then tried the FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES option, but it seems it doesn't work.

```
filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);
```

Ok, at this point I could do a subsequent find/replace of all the `&#39` instances. But it feels a little dumb. Any smarter way maybe?

Comment: Doesnt seem dumb to me. `Obviously, no one wants to read &#39 on a email message` So you replace those with what you want them to see. Or you could use `htmlspecialchars()` at the outset.

Comment: Maybe 
`htmlspecialchars_decode()` better than `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but why would you be filtering an email message?

Comment: It's not clear what the context is for your issue - can you post your code? Generally you don't need to encode anything as entities if you're using UTF-8 properly.

Comment: @zbee: for security reasons. Shouldn't I do it?

Comment: @Syncro: currently using phpMailer, and is properly setted to UTF-8. I'm filtering the message just to avoid security issues (I'm certainly not a security expert, though).

Comment: @LucaReghellin Are you reading emails? If so: wise, probably even more steps to consider as well. Are you sending data that is input by a user? If not, there's not much to consider on the outbound.

Comment: I'm sending data from a form, so user input

Comment: @LucaReghellin Are you sending it to another user, or is it a contact form for yourself? I would honestly focus on making the email more readable, such as interpreting line breaks. After all, there is pretty little outside of links that can be exploited via email at this point; [this](https://jonathannicol.com/blog/2006/12/09/securing-php-contact-forms/) is the most concerning thing I found, which may theoretically let people attach a file or change the from and to address to use your servers to spam people.